# How to use JUnit and Mockito to mock inner logic

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm kind of new to Junit and Mockito and trying to understand how to mock parts of logic of a class.

I have a method which does a http post and get call, but it might be a DB lookup. How do I mock the response from the HTTP call in this method

```
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpsConnection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
```

I mean there must a way to test my logic without doing to real http call or db lookup or whatever.

```
// HTTP GET request
public String sendGet(URL url) throws Exception {

    s_logger.debug("URL: " + url);
    HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Add request header
    httpsConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

    if (sessionId != null) {
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
    } else {
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("username", ACCOUNT_USERNAME);
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("password", ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);
    }

    httpsConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    httpsConnection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Print Request Header
    s_logger.debug("Request Header: " + httpsConnection.getRequestProperties());

    int responseCode = httpsConnection.getResponseCode();
    s_logger.debug("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = httpsConnection.getHeaderFields();
    s_logger.debug("Response Header: " + headerFields);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpsConnection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // Set Session ID
    final String SESSION_KEY = "sessionId";
    if (this.sessionId == null && httpsConnection.getHeaderFields().containsKey(SESSION_KEY)) {
        this.sessionId = httpsConnection.getHeaderFields().get(SESSION_KEY).get(0);
        s_logger.debug("SESSION ID : " + this.sessionId);
    }

    // print result
    s_logger.debug("RESPONSE: " + response.toString());
    return response.toString();
}
```

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

UPDATE:
I did kind of that has been suggested but I'm not sure if this makes sense, also I don't like the fact that these methods are now public.

```
    final URL url = new URL("https://test.com");
    final String request = "Test";
    HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = mock(HttpsURLConnection.class);


    final HttpConnectionClient httpSpy = spy(new HttpConnectionClient());
    Mockito.doReturn(httpsConnection).when(httpSpy).getConnection(url);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(httpSpy).sendRequest(httpsConnection, request);
    Mockito.doReturn(response).when(httpSpy).createBufferReader(httpsConnection);

    assertEquals(response,httpSpy.sendPost(url, request));
```

Comment: you are working with local URL?

Comment: No, I'm calling a remote service

Comment: Separate the "create connection" logic from the "read" logic and test them individually.

Comment: How does separating help ? it would be just another private method so we back back to the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hack is using spy and package-local methods:

```
public  class MyClass {
     public void myMethod() {
         //stuff
         stuffThatNeedsStubbing();
         //more stuff
     }

     void stuffThatNeedsStubbing() {
         //stuff that needs stub
     }
}

public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void example() {
        final MyClass myClass = spy(new MyClass());
        doNothing().when(myClass).stuffThatNeedsStubbing();
        myClass.myMethod();
    }
}
```

In your case, you could create a package-local method `BufferedReader createBufferedReader()`, and replace this with a mock in your test.

Answer (score 0):

The only tricky bit is the `url.openConnection()` because the URL is final class, so you cannot mock it. If you separate it, then you could use `mock(HttpsURLConnection.class)` using mockito and provide e.g. `ByteArrayInputStream` for the `getInputStream()` with mock-result.